# how to change opacity of links when clicked on a node in sankey diagram using d3 library

Tags: svg, d3.js

Description : data comes from json. nodes have property name it contains "loc1|April" while links have properties source : 0, target : 1, value : 2

so i have assigned the location of target node as a class to all the links using the code line in bold.

code :

```
var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
      .data(energy.links)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d){ return "link " + d.target.name; })
      .attr("d", path)
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.color = color(d.target.name.split("|")[0]); })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; });
```

So when i click on a particular node lets say node having loc1 as its location which i store it in variable loc.Then based on that location i select all the links having that location as a class and then based on that i want to change the opacity of the selected node to 0.5. But the following code doesn't work.

code:

```
   d3.selectAll(".node")
            .on("click",function(d){

                var loc = "." + d.name.split("|")[0];
                //console.log(loc);
                d3.selectAll(loc)
                  .style("stroke-opacity",.5);
            })
```

Comment: looks like your just selecting them incorrectly

Comment: how to go about it any hints ?

Comment: i wouldnt be too sure without working with the code infront of me so a JSFiddle will be beneficial but maybe put quotes around the loc selection. for example : (       ' ". ' + d.name.split("|")[0] + ' " '     )